# Meaning of “liberties taken with the word”

Tags: phrase-meaning

I can't even guess the meaning of the words '**liberties taken with the word**' in the last sentence. Could anyone explain it?

> Within Frost’s Multidimensional Perfectionism Scale (FMPS), researchers and the general public alike commonly see personal standards (PS) and organization (O) as positive forms of perfectionism.
>
> (....)
>
> Organization is arguably not even a part of perfectionism. Not all researchers agree with the liberties taken with the word.

(From 'How to Be an Imperfectionist' by Stephen Guise)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lexico "take liberties"](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/take_liberties)

> 1 Behave in an unduly familiar manner toward a person.
> *you've taken too many liberties with me*

> 2 Treat something freely, without strict faithfulness to the facts or to an original.
> *The scriptwriter has taken few liberties with the original narrative*

The word "liberty" means freedom. To **take liberties with** is to act **too freely** toward someone or something, The sense of
*Not all researchers agree with the liberties taken with the word.*
is
*Some researchers think that the word has been used too freely, in a way not faithful to its original meaning.*

Note that if you are dealing with an idiom, some dictionaries may have a definition for it in its simplest form. The definition above was found by looking at "onelook.com" for "take liberties".

Comment: It now became much clear to me! Thanks for your explanation.